# Excelで数値の各４桁をカンマで別けた上で0値を非表示

Tags: excel

Excelは専門外ですから、セルの表示形式は理解していなく、下記の公式は他の情報源からコピペされました。

先ずは、数値の各４桁をカンマで別けたいです。
この目標は既に達し、公式は「`[>99999999]0!,0000!,0000;[>9999]0!,0000;0`」となります。

0を非表示にしたい時、表示形式`0;-0;;@`にすれば宜しいですが、上記の公式との組み合わせる方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

書式の最後にゼロを指定しない場合、0は非表示になります。

```
[>99999999]0!,0000!,0000;[>9999]0!,0000;
```

値が正、負、0の書式を`;`で区切って指定します。

Comment: ご回答に感謝します！